# Django testing pluggable apps and custom settings

Tags: django, unit-testing, settings

I have a pluggable app for Django that provides a few forms. The forms have a few settings associated with them that control some of the forms' behavior (e.g., labels, initial values, and so on).

I've followed a [blog post](http://passingcuriosity.com/2010/default-settings-for-django-applications/) to set the default settings for the pluggable app, and that works well under normal circumstances. However, in tests, where I provide overrides, the overrides do not get applied at all.

Here's the code for one of the forms:

```
if settings.CURRENCY_FORM_INCLUDE_EMPTY:
    currencies.insert(0, (settings.CURRENCY_FORM_EMPTY_VALUE,
                          settings.CURRENCY_FORM_EMPTY_LABEL))

class CurrencyForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=currencies,
        label=settings.CURRENCY_FORM_LABEL,
        initial=settings.CURRENCY_FORM_INITIAL_VALUE)
```

Obviously, the moment class is defined, settings like label and inital value are applied immediately, so overrides have no effect on them.

I ended up with a rather hackish solugion of evaluating all settings in form's `__init__` method:

```
class CurrencyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CurrencyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        choices = list(currencies)

        if settings.CURRENCY_FORM_INCLUDE_EMPTY:
            choices.insert(0, (settings.CURRENCY_FORM_EMPTY_VALUE,
                               settings.CURRENCY_FORM_EMPTY_LABEL))

        self.fields['currency'].label = settings.CURRENCY_FORM_LABEL
        self.fields['currency'].choices = choices
        self.fields['currency'].initial = kwargs.get(
            'initial', {}
        ).get('currency', settings.CURRENCY_FORM_INITIAL_VALUE)

    currency = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                                 choices=())
```

Obviously, lots of moving parts. I'm not very happy with this code. How do I properly test the settings' effect on the forms without resorting to these hacks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're trying to do. But as an advice, you should think this in a more object oriented way. For example, instead of using that `if` statement, you should define everything and just plug what you use.

If you have 2 forms, and want to use 1 of them at each time, you could have some setting, like:

```
settings.FORM_TO_USE = CurrencyForm
```

And when you want to instantiate you can do:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = settings.FORM_TO_USE()
```

Lastly, try to manage the tests separate from the configuration. If you're unittesting django, it shouldn't care what the settings are.

Comment: I'm testing the configuration itself, since this is a pluggable app. I want to make sure configuration has intended effect.